# Is this a type of fruit fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Taipei, and these flying insects are about 2-4 millimeters long (body length). They are very active when it's over roughly 24C indoors, and will fly, land and run around randomly on interesting surfaces then fly again, all in one continuous motion.

Some have moved into my apartment again.

They are attracted to food, especially *coffee grounds!*, vinegar, bread, and dark, moist areas. I can use these attractants to catch them inside bottles or plastic bags, but can't ever seem to get the last one.

I see them fly around while mating end-to-end (twice as long as a single fly) and they often go right past my face while doing so as if to say "ha! there's more of us on the way!"

The heads seem smaller than in images of common fruit flies that I've seen.

Are these likely to be fruit flies, or something else? I don't need an exact species identification, I'd just like have some kind of classification to describe them with besides "little flies".

In this [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/64219/27918) to a related but different question, it was proposed that they were something very different, but I don't think that's the case.

---

Photos: the best I cold do with my cell phone plus a magnifying lens.

[image]

Comment: Didn't the last answer say it was a baby cockroach

Comment: @SonicSplasher That was an answer to a question about pesticides, not a species identification question, so even though it was suggested, I'm pretty sure these are not baby cockroaches. See my [comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/why-wont-this-spray-kill-this-bug-household-insecticide-could-it-be-so-selec/64219#comment144859_64219) there. I can't help it that that answer's formatting makes it look like it's answering a species id question.

Comment: Search for drosophila buzzati and drosophila buskcii and drosophila simulans

Comment: This has been recently bumped by community; I add this comment for closure. This is a six-legged (hexapod) two winged (dipteran) fly. It is a female [drosophilid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosophilidae), and identifying the species and subspecies from such a photo is impossible; typically, correct identification requires careful morphological assessment using a microscope, by a specialist/insect taxonomist. I don't think this fly is shaped like a _Drosophilia melanogaster_ member. It seems a bit too long. Source: personal daily experience with manipulating fruit flies on a CO2 pad.

Comment: @SPr Thanks for your comment! The "ultimate closure" in Stack Exchange is of course acceptance. If you'd consider writing up something along the lines of "...without the possibility of genetic analysis... correct identification requires careful morphological assessment using a microscope, by a specialist/insect taxonomist." I could probably accept it.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Commom fruit fly]
  
I can't pinpoint on the species name but a quick **common fruit fly** should give you a image which look very similar to the one in your photos.

- these Bois are around 1/8 in inches long
  -striated abdomen

Hope this is the one

Comment: I mentioned that, but: "The heads seem smaller than in images of common fruit flies that I've seen." Your guys have a big head with a tiny neck, my guys seem to have a "unibody"

Comment: The thing is baby roaches cannot fly and the ones you mentioned are flying so this is the most similar one I can come up with or maybe some sort of Taipei variant

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think they did, I'm glad to know for sure now. I really appreciate the confirmation on the "no fly" baby roaches.

Comment: What kind of insect is a Bois?

Comment: "bois" here was another word for boys and i used boys informally to you know call them that without addressing them with their scientific name